# Star operator, exterior product

Tags: integration, volume, exterior-algebra, adjoint-operators, hodge-theory

Let $\ast$ be the star operator $$\ast:\Lambda^p(V)\to \Lambda^{d-p}(V)$$
so that we have $$\ast(e_{i_1}\wedge...\wedge e_{i_p})=e_{j_1}...\wedge e_{j_{d-p}}$$
where
$$e_{i_1},...,e_{i_p},e_{j_1},...,e_{j_{d-p}}$$
is a positive basis of $V$.
For $v,w\in\Lambda^p(V)$ we have $$\langle v,w\rangle=\ast(w\wedge \ast v)=\ast(v\wedge \ast w).$$

Why then $$\ast(1)=\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}dx^1\wedge ...\wedge dx^d$$
and also how do we use the above property to yield
$$\int_M \langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\ast(1)=\int_M \alpha\wedge \ast\beta$$
for $\alpha,\beta\in \Omega^p(M)$ with compact support?

Comment: Shouldn't $e_{i_1},...,e_{i_p},e_{j_1},...,e_{j_{d-p}}$ be a positive basis for $V^*$?

Comment: Jurgen Jost [here](http://download.library1.org/main/858000/7e2f1980276af27bfce410bcf5e038d9/%28Universitext%29%20J%C3%BCrgen%20Jost%20%28auth.%29-Riemannian%20Geometry%20and%20Geometric%20Analysis%20-Springer-Verlag%20Berlin%20Heidelberg%20%282011%29.pdf) on the page 103 in line 9 writes for $V$.

Comment: Okay. Anyway, note that $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is an ON-basis while $dx^1, \ldots, dx^n$ is not necessarily ON.

Comment: OK. And can you please answer my entire question ?

Comment: Don't be distracted by the integral or the requirement for compact support.  Show that $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\,{\star}(1)=\alpha\wedge{\star}\beta$, which almost trivially gives you the final result from what you have stated.

Comment: @qman This is exactly what I cannot show. Any hint about your equality?

Comment: You have that $\langle v,w\rangle={\star}(v\wedge{\star}w)$, from which it follows that ${\star}\langle v,w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle\,{\star}(1)={\star}{\star}(v\wedge{\star}w)$.  So it remains to show that ${\star}\circ{\star}=\mathrm{id}$ when applied to $\Lambda^d(V)$, for which your first identity should suffice (used twice).

Comment: @qman How have you derived $\ast \langle v,w \rangle=\langle v,w\rangle\ast (1)$ ?

Comment: $\langle v,w\rangle$ is a real number (scalar or 0-form) and ${\star}$ is linear. If you want to distinguish notationally between a 0-form and a real number consistently by using parenthesis, it should be written ${\star}(\langle v,w\rangle)=\langle v,w\rangle{\star}(1)$.